# callback from flashembed of jquery Tools

Tags: api, callback, swfobject, jquery-tools, onreadystatechange

jQuery Tools includes a flashembed API which accepts many parameters. Is there one which accepts callback function and fires after the success state of the flash player load event?

`playerdiv.flashembed(url+'/VIPlayer.swf','knds_player',300,250,'8.0.0',false,flashVars);`

Information: [official website](http://flowplayer.org/tools/toolbox/flashembed.html).

Note: This is possible in [Google swfobject library](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation) as below:

`swfobject.embedSWF(url+'/VIPlayer.swf','knds_player',300,250,'8.0.0',false,flashVars,callBack);`

function callBack(event){
   event after successful display of code
}

But I need to use only flashembed. Can you please help me here?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flashembed method has an `onFail` argument which takes a callback as a value:

```
$("#flash").flashembed({
   src: flashSWF,
   version:[10,0],
   id:"flashObj",
   width: 500,
   height: 300,
   wmode: "opaque",
   cachebusting: "false",
   allowscriptaccess: "always",
   api: "false",
   scale: "noscale",
   menu: "false",
   onFail: flasherror("#flash")
   })
```

It inadvertently fires on both success AND failure. Search for the `,` character to distinguish between the two states. On error, it shows up as the delimiter in the version string, such as `11,0` rather than `11.0`:

```
function flashError(domnode, newtext){

function failState()
  {
  if ($(domnode).html().search(/,/) !== -1) //player failed to load
    {
    newtext = $(domnode).html(); // store default error string
    $(domnode).empty();
    $(domnode).append(newtext.replace(/,/g,".")); // replace comma with period
    if ($(domnode).hasClass("flashmsg") === false)
      {
      $(domnode).addClass("flashmsg"); // add class to custom error element
      }
    }
  else
    {
    //success logic
    }        
}

// observer constructor
var cursor =
typeof window.hasOwnProperty === "function" ?
  window.hasOwnProperty("WebKitMutationObserver")
    ? new WebKitMutationObserver(startValidation)
    : window.hasOwnProperty("MutationObserver")
      ? new MutationObserver(startValidation)
      : false
        : false
  ;

//Use observer event if it exists
if (cursor)       
  {
  //Bind observer event to text child of the dom node
  cursor.observe($(domnode).get(0), { childList: true } );
  return;
  }
//Use mutation event as a fallback
else if (!!document.addEventListener)
  {
  $(domnode).get(0).addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", failState, false); 
  }
//Use readystatechange event for legacy IE
else
  {
  $(domnode).get(0).addBehavior("foo.htc");
  $(domnode).get(0).attachEvent("onreadystatechange", failState);
  }
```

**References**

- [FlashEmbed Configuration](http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/configuration/player.html)
- [Migrating mutation and property change events to mutation observers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265032)