# Availability of MutationObservers in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-manipulation, mutation-observers

AFAIK mutation observers are not available yet in IE. Chrome, Safari, Firefox have their implementations and its working its way through the standardization process. I'm wondering if anyone (preferably MS employee) knows the story with IE, or might give me a pointer to an article I missed.

Comment: You're wondering why IE is behind others with implementing something?

Comment: sadly, http://caniuse.com is silent on the topic.

Comment: Thanks Jan. Ian, I'm not wondering why they're behind, I'm wondering how long they'll be behind, and if they already offer some faster alternative to binding to the DOM mutation events.

Answer (score 3):

IE 11 supports `MutationObservers` natively. For IE 9-10 you can use this polyfill:
https://github.com/Polymer/MutationObservers

Answer (score 1):

There's a recent article on [Windows 8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/09/19/make-your-html-javascript-app-accessible.aspx) app development which uses `onpropertychange` to handle DOM mutation.

> Example 4: Handle onpropertychange for ARIA-selected property to detect programmatic change of tab selection.

```
    tabElement.attachEvent("onpropertychange", selectionChanged);

    function selectionChanged(event) 
     {
     if (event.propertyName === "aria-selected")
       {
       if (event.srcElement.getAttribute("aria-selected") === "true") 
         {
         // execute code to load the content that corresponds with the selected tab element 
         } 
       else 
         {
         // execute code for deselected tab, if needed
         }
       }
     }
```

**References**

- [Make your HTML/JavaScript app accessible – Windows 8 app developer blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsappdev/2012/09/19/make-your-htmljavascript-app-accessible/)
- [onpropertychange for a textbox in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919428/)
- [callback from flashembed of jquery Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325189/)

Answer (score 0):

For compatibility with IE9-10, https://github.com/webmodules/mutation-observer exposes the native MutationObserver API provided by the browser, or a polyfill based on mutation events.